# Unable to execute a do-while loop completely

Tags: c, while-loop, char, scanf

I am trying to execute a small program using `do-while`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
char another;
int num;
do
{
    printf("Enter a number");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    printf("Square of %d id %d",num,num*num);
    printf("Want to another another number y/n");
    scanf("%c",&another);
}while(another=='y');
}
```

Now when I try to execute the program, it runs fine. I input a number and it displays its square. And then I see `Want to enter another number y/n`. But as soon as I press any key (y or n), the program exits itself before I can press enter to provide the input. I tried it many times but no success.

But the program runs fine if I ask the user to input either 1 or 2(in place of y/n). In that case it takes an integer input and can check the while block. If `another == 1`, the program runs again.

My problem is that why can't I check for a character in the `while` condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is that after `scanf` gets `num`, the new line is still in the buffer, so it will be processed by the next `scanf` with `%c` format specifier. A direct way of fixing it is to use:

```
scanf(" %c", &another);
//     ^space
```

Note that your original `scanf("%c:,&another);` won't compile, but I assume that's a typo. And always use `int main`, or it's undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks bro. You really helped me a lot. I was fed up thinking what's the problem with my code. You saved me. But can you please explain why I need a space before the %c and not needed in %d??

Comment: @user2899258 Basically it's because a new line character is a valid character but not a valid integer, so `scanf` will only process the white space character(including new line) when the format specifier has `[`, `c`,or `n`. And adding a space before `%c` would make `scanf` ignore any white space before the character you need.